# ¿Cómo evitar que se pueda modificar cierto campo en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

Al editar una entidad existente todos los campos (excepto las claves) son modificables. ¿Hay alguna manera de indica que cierto campo no sea modificable?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar cualquier propiedad de la vista de solo lectura usando la anotación [@ReadOnly](https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/apidocs/org/openxava/annotations/ReadOnly.html):

```
@ReadOnly
private String nombre;
```

Además, puedes definir la propiedad no modificable para cierta vista:

```
@ReadOnly(forViews="AlgunosMiembroSoloLectura")
private String nombre;
```

@ReadOnly también se puede aplicar a referencias:

```
@ReadOnly @ManyToOne
private Cliente cliente;
```

Y colecciones:

```
@ReadOnly @OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente")
private Collection<Factura> facturas;
```